# "requirement on" VS "requirement for"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. With increased **requirements on** the reliability of automotive electronics, integrated solutions are in higher demand
> 2. With increased **requirements for** the reliability of automotive electronics, integrated solutions are in higher demand
> 3. With increased **demand on** the reliability of automotive electronics, integrated solutions are in higher demand
> 4. With increased **demand for** the reliability of automotive electronics, integrated solutions are in higher demand

Which one is the most suitable one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker of American English I would say that they are all somewhat awkward and #2 and #4 are better than the others. I find it hard to determine what any of them really mean.

Depending on the larger context I would rephrase these to make three better sounding sentences to choose from

> With increased requirements for reliability in automotive electronics...
>   With increased demand on automotive electronics...
>   With increased demand for reliable automotive electronics...